# ajax post for django template

Tags: jquery, ajax, django-templates, methods

HI all,

I have a problem when i want to submit value then full page again reload. 
I want to update my table with asynchronous call, that specific information will be loaded but full page not... plz help me aboput this...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the jquery From plugin.  Will help you submit a form via ajax and then you can use the data that is sent back and update your table.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

something like:

```
$('#myForm1').ajaxForm({
    target: '#someid'
});
```

That will handle submitting the form via ajax and then what ever gets sent back will replace whatever is in

Should get you started in the right direction.